# Drawing of random placed circle sometimes turn into oval

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I have a small program that show a circle, and when you click on that circle it re-appears somewhere else on the screen.

This works good in 90% of the cases, but sometimes the circle is buggy. It can be that it appears outside the view, appears as an oval instead of circle, or is placed halfway outside the view.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, what am I doing wrong?

Screens:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Code example:

```
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    int margin = 20;

    Button ball;
    TextView debug;
    RelativeLayout mRel;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ballParams;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Create a debug label
        debug = new TextView(this);

        // Create a new ball
        ball = new Button(this);
        ball.SetBackgroundDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.round_button));
        ball.Click += (o, e) => {
             RandomizePosition();
        };

        // Set ball parameters
        ballParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

        // Create relative layout
        mRel = new RelativeLayout(this);
        mRel.SetBackgroundColor(Color.AntiqueWhite);
        mRel.AddView(ball);
        mRel.AddView(debug);
        SetContentView(mRel);

        // Randmize the ball position
        RandomizePosition ();
    }

    void RandomizePosition ()
    {
        // Get height and width
        Display display = WindowManager.DefaultDisplay;
        int width = display.Width;
        int height = display.Height;
        int relativeBallSize = ((((width * 2) + (height * 2)) / 100) * 3);

        // Set random parameters
        Random r = new Random();
        int maxWidth = (width - relativeBallSize);
        int maxHeight = (height - relativeBallSize);
        int x = r.Next(margin, (maxWidth < margin) ? margin : maxWidth);
        int y = r.Next(margin, (maxHeight < margin) ? margin : maxHeight);

        // Place the ball randomly
        ballParams.SetMargins(x, y, x, y);
        ball.LayoutParameters = ballParams;
        ball.SetHeight(relativeBallSize);
        ball.SetWidth(relativeBallSize);

        debug.SetText(string.Format("X = {0}, Y = {1}, Width = {2}, Height = {3}, Ball Width = {4}, Ball Height = {5}, Ball size = {6}", x, y, width, height, ball.Width, ball.Height, relativeBallSize), TextView.BufferType.Normal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give more detail.  Why is 2 a fail?  The width and height are both 33 and given the example in 1 where height is 10, looks correct.  In 3, the x and y, going by the apparent size of the view from 1 and 2 also looks correct.  What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `r.Next` method is working correctly I think the problem is here:

`ballParams.SetMargins(x, y, x, y);`

You're setting the margins for the left,top,right,bottom respectively and I don't think you mean to be setting the right and bottom margins. You might want to try using the setX and setY methods instead.

Comment: Yes, thanks. That was part of the issue. It solved the part where it was outside the view. But it did not solve the part where it was shown as an oval. But that was because I did not take into consideration the title and status bar height. Now it works.